# Filter Logic in apex in salesforce

Tags: apex, soql, query

How do I create a filter button and logic in apex for opportunity object? I have created the stage picklist.
This is my code-

```
public class abc 
{
        public List<selectOption> getSelectOptions() 
        { 
            List<selectOption> options = new List<selectOption>();
            options.add(new selectOption('Select','Select'));
            options.add(new SelectOption('Qualification','Qualification'));
            options.add(new SelectOption('Negotiation/Review','Negotiation/Review'));
            options.add(new SelectOption('Closed Won','Closed Won'));
            options.add(new SelectOption('Closed Lost','Closed Lost'));

            return options;
        }

       public String selectedVal{get;set;}
       public list<Opportunity> Opps{get;set;} 

       public abc(){}

      public pageReference oppList()
      {
      if(selectedVal!=null) 
      {
         Opps= [select name,type,CloseDate from Opportunity where StageName=: selectedVal];
      }
      return null;

      } 

}
```

---

```
<apex:page controller="abc">
  <apex:form > 
   Stage   <apex:SelectList id="List" value="{!selectedVal}" size="1">
                    <apex:actionSupport action="{!oppList}" event="onchange"
                    reRender="a"/>
                    <apex:selectOptions value="{!selectOptions}" />
           </apex:SelectList>

      <apex:pageBlock id="a" >
           <apex:pageBlockTable value="{!opps}" var="v">
            <apex:column value="{!v.name}"/>
            <apex:column value="{!v.type}"/>
            <apex:column value="{!v.CloseDate}"/>
           </apex:pageBlockTable>
      </apex:pageBlock>
  </apex:form> 
</apex:page>
```

Comment: Where did you stuck?

Comment: I want to know how to put filter button and logic. When user selects any stage and clicks on filter button, the below table should get refreshed to populate opportunities owned by logged in user and having stage equal to stage selected.

Answer (score 2):

You don't need a button. It can be done by existing `actionsupport` itself. You need to modify only the query in `oppList()` as:

```
Opps = [SELECT Name, Type, CloseDate 
    FROM Opportunity 
    WHERE StageName = :selectedVal 
        AND OwnerId = :Userinfo.getuserId()];
```

If you need a button for this, try:

```
<apex:commandButton value="Get Opportunities" action="{!oppList}" reRender="a"/>
```

And remove existing `actionsupport`